# MinGW on Windows Make Command Cannot Find -lncurses

Tags: c, windows, makefile, mingw

I am trying to run C programs on Windows with MinGW. Most files are copied from a Linux server, including the makefile. In my makefile I have

```
gcc -g -o $@ $^  -L. -lncurses -lm
```

But when I executed `make NAME` I got:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lncurses
```

I have checked in MinGW manager, both `mingw32-ncurse` and `mingw32-libncurse` has been installed.

Where could I be missing? Is there a way to fix that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the name of the library in mingw? I am noticing 2 possible issues: 1. Library is called `ncurse` not `ncurse/s/` 2. Possibly `mingw-` is prepended to `ncurse`?

It's been a while since I've used MinGW, I used Cygwin more often, years ago... is WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) not work for what you are doing? It's is typically much better than both MinGW and Cygwin.